# hiding project configuration in Hudson

Tags: hudson

I want to setup Hudson in a way that other users can easily create new jobs with some parameters already in place (e.g. the artifact path). Bonus points if they cannot modify those parameters. Extra bonus points if I can hide extra configuration that they don't need to use.

Right now, I've created a Template job, and have the users copy from it whenever they want to create a new job. This works fine, but if I want to change some configuration in the Template, then I have to manually edit all the already created job.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The [Template Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Template+Project+Plugin) should meet some of your needs; I don't think you'll be able to hide any of the configuration, though.

Comment: But I don't think that would be better than creating a Template job and copying from it, wouldn't it? I still wouldn't be able to update the template and then have all the created project be automatically updated.